# SQL count with some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Original Table:

```
Initialdate OriginalTime Gate1 Destindate DestinationTime Gate2
20151001    00           A     20151001   00              B
20151001    00           A     20151001   00              B
20151001    00           A     20151001   00              C
20151001    01           A     20151001   01              A
20151001    01           A     20151001   01              B
20151001    01           A     20151001   01              B
20151001    01           A     20151001   01              B
20151001    01           B     20151001   01              A
```

How to get table as follow:

```
Initialdate OriginalTime Gate1 Destindate DestinationTime Gate2  Freq
 20151001    00           A     20151001   00              B     2
 20151001    00           A     20151001   00              C     1
 20151001    01           A     20151001   01              A     1
 20151001    01           A     20151001   01              B     3
 20151001    01           B     20151001   01              A     1
```

Think so many days to solve this, but I cant handle it.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: A simple `COUNT` will solve this: `SELECT *,
 Freq = COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY
 InitialDate, OriginalTime, Gate1,
 DestinDate, DestinationTime, Gate2`

Comment: I think its a complicated question, so i tried to use IF THEN ELSE to do this. but havent reached the goal.

Comment: What? Can you explain what you want to achieve? Did the query I gave you work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way.

```
 SELECT Initialdate, OriginalTime, Gate1, 
      Destindate, DestinationTime, Gate2, 
      COUNT(1) as Freq
 FROM TABLE1
 GROUP BY Initialdate, OriginalTime, Gate1, 
      Destindate, DestinationTime, Gate2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window functions in SQL2005+:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *,
      COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Initialdate, OriginalTime, Gate1, Destindate, DestinationTime, Gate2) AS Freq
FROM Your_Table
```